# ¿Por que al importar un Query object, el SQL statement que se genera es diferente al del origen?

Tags: genexus

Tengo un objeto query el cual exporte e importe a otra KB, al revisar el SQL statement, me doy cuenta que es distinto, y la consulta generada me da un error SQL al momento de desplegarlo en un Web Panel.
Probé realizando un export completo de la KB de origen y regenerando las tablas(build->Create Database Tables) pero aun así, en la KB destino me sigue generando un SQL statement incorrecto.
Lo que mas me llama la atención, es que al hacer un export completo en viceversa, la KB de origen me siga manteniendo correcto el SQL statement.
Estoy trabajando con Genexus16u11.